# Can't step into string.h function with GDB

Tags: c, gdb

Having trouble stepping into `string.h` in GDB 7.5. Here's a simple example program:

**Source code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str1[20];
    strcpy(str1, "STEP INTO ME\n");
    printf(str1);
}
```

**Compiled:** `~$ gcc -g foo.c`

**Invoked:**  `~$ gdb -q ./a.out`

**GDB:**

```
(gdb) break 5
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048471: file foo.c, line 6.
(gdb) break strcpy
Function "strcpy" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y

Breakpoint 2 (strcpy) pending.
(gdb) run 
Starting program: /home/user/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at foo.c:6
6               strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
(gdb) step
7               printf(str_a);
```

Shouldn't I be in the string library at this point? Instead it continues to the printf().

---

**EDIT:**

Scott's suggestion "worked", but not in the expected manner.

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at foo.c:6
6               strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
(gdb) i r $eip
eip            0x80484a1        0x80484a1 <main+21>
(gdb) step

Breakpoint 2, __strcpy_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcpy-ssse3.S:78
78      ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcpy-ssse3.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) i r $eip
eip            0xb7e9c820       0xb7e9c820 <__strcpy_ssse3>
```

I am surprised at the directory in `78`... expected something like: `/lib/.../cmov/libc.so.6`. And the claim that there is no such file or directory.

Comment: @skirkpatrick: This is wrong, at least on most systems (OS X, Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora...).  Shared libraries *are* compiled with debugging symbols.  The real question is whether those symbols are installed.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: After a quick search, it looks like you're right. Sorry for the misinformation; I'll remove my comment.

Comment: The debug symbols are not part of the .so which reside in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Instead they reside in a directory which gdb searches such as `/usr/lib/debug`. This info can be obtained by running `show debug-file-directory` in `gdb`. These files contain only debug information without any `.text` or `.data` sections of the `.so`. And yes you need to install them separately.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Recompile your code with `gcc -fno-builtin -g foo.c` and the gdb `step` command will work. (See [-fno-builtin documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-fno_002dbuiltin-107)). Otherwise small `strcpy()`, `memcpy()` calls would often be translated into open coded data movement instructions, e.g. on x86-64:

```
4   int main() {
   0x000000000040052c <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040052d <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400530 <+4>: sub    $0x20,%rsp

5       char str1[20];
6       strcpy(str1, "STEP INTO ME\n");
   0x0000000000400534 <+8>: lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400538 <+12>:    movl   $0x50455453,(%rax)
   0x000000000040053e <+18>:    movl   $0x544e4920,0x4(%rax)
   0x0000000000400545 <+25>:    movl   $0x454d204f,0x8(%rax)
   0x000000000040054c <+32>:    movw   $0xa,0xc(%rax)

7       printf(str1);
   0x0000000000400552 <+38>:    lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400556 <+42>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000400559 <+45>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040055e <+50>:    callq  0x400410 <printf@plt>

8   }
   0x0000000000400563 <+55>:    leaveq 
   0x0000000000400564 <+56>:    retq
```

You can see the `strpcy()` call being compiled into multiple **MOV** instructions.

`gcc -fno-builtin` compiles the same program into:

```
4   int main() {
   0x000000000040057c <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040057d <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400580 <+4>: sub    $0x20,%rsp

5       char str1[20];
6       strcpy(str1, "STEP INTO ME\n");
   0x0000000000400584 <+8>: lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400588 <+12>:    mov    $0x400660,%esi
   0x000000000040058d <+17>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000400590 <+20>:    callq  0x400450 <strcpy@plt>

7       printf(str1);
   0x0000000000400595 <+25>:    lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400599 <+29>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x000000000040059c <+32>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000004005a1 <+37>:    callq  0x400460 <printf@plt>

8   }
   0x00000000004005a6 <+42>:    leaveq 
   0x00000000004005a7 <+43>:    retq
```

and you can see the call to `<strcpy@plt>`.

Assuming you wanted to step into `strcpy()` to study its implementation, you'd want to have debug info for libc.so installed. Unfortunately the way to get debug info differs between Linux distros. On Fedora it's as simple as `debuginfo-install glibc`. It takes more steps on Ubuntu and Debian. This [RPM DPKG Rosetta Stone](http://itrs.tw/wiki/RPM_DPKG_Rosetta_Stone) page have links to instructions for Fedora, Ubuntu and Debian (search for **debuginfo**).

Since you're on Ubuntu 12.10 and actually want to see the `strcpy()` assembly source code:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg
$ sudo apt-get source libc6-dev
$ gdb ./a.out
(gdb) directory eglibc-2.15/sysdeps
Source directories searched: /home/scottt/eglibc-2.15/sysdeps:$cdir:$cwd
(gdb) break strcpy
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400450
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/scottt/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, __strcpy_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcpy.S:32
32      movq %rsi, %rcx     /* Source register. */
```

Comment: Is `t.c` supposed to represent `foo.c` (in this case) or is that a file I am supposed to link with?

Comment: I tried this. Steps in, but it goes to an unexpected directory and says *No such file or directory*. I'll post the results in my question... the formatting will be brutal in a comment.

Comment: @d0rmLife: it looks like strcpy is implemented in assembly in glibc

Comment: @d0rmLife, `t.c` was indeed just my shorter name for `foo.c` :)
After you step into an optimized implementation of strcpy() is where you really want to have debug info for libc.so installed to make sense of things.

Comment: I wanted to make sure it wasn't some unusual file! :) ...posted the output in my question. I would appreciate any ideas you might have on the directory.

Comment: @d0rmLife, I've edited my answer. See the last paragraph. What Linux distro are you using?

Comment: Having trouble understanding the proper shell commands to get the package. `sudo apt-get install debuginfo-install` doesn't do it.... i see `debuginfo-install kernel` in the example, but that says it is for debugging the kernel.

Comment: @d0rmLife, I've updated my answer with detailed instructions for Ubuntu. Now, I don't usually give this level of customer service on StackOverflow ;)

Comment: Hah, well it is my good fortune then. :) **You're a gentleman and a scholar, thank you for your assistance!**  *BTW...your professional customer service must be unparalleled!* :P ... I will say, though, who would have thought how involved it would be to debug C libraries in Ubuntu 12. I have done it in older distros and it was far more straight forward. **I feel like something is amiss.** Anyways, it did work.

Answer (score 3):

You tried to set a breakpoint for a function defined in the string library usually part of the `standard C library - libc.so`

And as `gdb` informs you:

```
(gdb) break strcpy
Function "strcpy" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y

Breakpoint 2 (strcpy) pending.
```

the library is not loaded yet.

But the real problem is, even when the library is loaded, if the library i.e. `libc.so` does not have debug symbols in it, you would not be able to step through the code within the library using `gdb`.

You could enable verbose mode to see which symbols, `gdb` is able to load:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400914: file test.cpp, line 7.
(gdb) set verbose on
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/agururaghave/.scratch/gdb-test/test 
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Reading symbols from system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffb000...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Registering libstdc++-v6 pretty-printer for /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 ...
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/libm.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libm.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/libc.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libc.so.6

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.cpp:7
7       bool result = myObj1 < myObj2;
```

This line for example tells you whether it was able to get the symbols for libc.so:

```
Reading symbols from /lib64/libc.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

You could then figure out where the debug symbols are picked up from using `show debug-file-directory`:

```
(gdb) show debug-file-directory 
The directory where separate debug symbols are searched for is "/usr/lib/debug".
```

As you see `/usr/lib/debug` here does not contain the full .so with debug symbols. Instead it only has the debug info without any `.text` or `.data` sections of the actual libc.so which the program uses for execution.

The solution to install the debug info for libraries would be distro specific.

I think the package is called `libc6-dbg` on the debian based distros. On my openSUSE machine, it seems to be called `glibc-debuginfo`

BTW, +1 on `scottt`'s suggestion of using `-fno-builtin` so that gcc does not use its built-in methods for functions like `strcpy` and other standard ones defined as part of C standard.

Comment: Whether libc.so has debug info is not the problem here. Since the program is dynamically linked, if there exists a call to strcpy() that goes through the PLT, gdb would catch it. The problem here is that the gcc option `-fno-buitin` was not passed, and the call to strcpy() in the source was translated into store instructions.

Comment: Any idea what the package might be called for Ubuntu 12?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg`

Comment: @scottt - Good catch, you're actually right. I didn't know gcc uses builtins for functions like strcpy.

Comment: Got the package, still not stepping in. Does it require special options in compiling/invoking?

Comment: @d0rmLife - Try scottt's solution i.e. compile your program with `-fno-builtin` and you should see gdb stepping into the function with that.

Comment: I did, and it does, but not how I expect. Will post the output in question for better formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have any symbols for your C library. Try `stepi`, but be prepared to see only assembly instructions.

Comment: @d0rmLife, are you sure?  How did you check?

Comment: By running `GDB` and using `stepi`. No, I guess I'm not positive but it didn't seem to. At least, not in the usual way...

Comment: @d0rmLife, and the PC didn't change when you did that?  That surprises me.

Comment: Output was different, but it didn't acknowledge being in a different library (expected something like `/lib/...libc.so...`)