# How to fix GDB breakpoints

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I made this simple program in C for debugging purposes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str_a[20];

    strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
    printf(str_a);
}
```

and when debugging the program using GDB, I set breakpoints at lines 6 (the blank line), line 7 (the strcpy function), and line 8 (the print). So this is what I did:

```
(gdb) break 6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004ee: file char_array.c, line 6.
(gdb) break strcpy
Function "strcpy" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 2 (strcpy) pending.
(gdb) break 8
Breakpoint 3 at 0x400510: file char_array.c, line 8.
```

For my point of view, so far so good. but now a problem arises when I run the program:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/Documents/Scripts/C Scripts/char_array 
Breakpoint 1, main () at char_array.c:7
7               strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
(gdb) i r rip
rip            0x4004ee 0x4004ee <main+8>
```

This shows the RIP register is still in main. Continuing:

```
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, main () at char_array.c:8
8               printf(str_a);
```

Obviously, the program skipped the second breakpoint (at strcpy), but why?? I can't see any reason for this. And to assure the program skipped the breakpoint, I looked again at the RIP register:

```
(gdb) i r rip
rip            0x400510 0x400510 <main+42>
```

So the RIP register didn't jump to the shared library and is still in main(). What's the reason for this?! It has been disturbing me for a lot of time.

Comment: How did you compile the program? Did you include debugging info (`-g`), did you enable optimizations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't step into string.h function with GDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306090/cant-step-into-string-h-function-with-gdb)

Comment: The program flow as GDB presents it to you can appear to differ from that implied by the source if you compiled with any optimization enabled.  Use gcc's `-O0` option to turn off all optimization.

Comment: where is the function: `print()` found?  Did you actually mean `printf()`?

Comment: user3629249 yes I meant printf()

Comment: EOF This is how I comliled the program: gcc -g -o char_array char_array.c