# Debugging symbols installation

Tags: debugging, gdb, debian

I'm trying to download debugging symbols to Debian OS, I've done some research and saw this web : https://wiki.debian.org/HowToGetABacktrace , but i could not know the name of the package to download  it. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what app you want to debug. Say you want to debug `/bin/ls`.

First you need to find out what package provides this file:

```
$ dpkg -S /bin/ls
coreutils: /bin/ls
```

Package name is `coreutils`. Next you need to install debug symbols for this package following instructions in https://wiki.debian.org/HowToGetABacktrace#Installing_the_debugging_symbols. It should be either `coreutils-dbgsym` or `coreutils-dbg` package. So the command to install debug symbols package would be one of these:

```
 # apt-get install coreutils-dbgsym
```

or

```
 # apt-get install coreutils-dbg
```

Comment: I had this problem when I was debugging : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119328/strcpy-sse2-unaligned-with-fno-builtin . Then I did some research and I saw this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306090/cant-step-into-string-h-function-with-gdb/15306144#15306144 which told you to install debug symbols, but I still could not know what package should I download as I don't know what app I'm debugging either ( sorry, cause I'm new to Kali linux and Debian OS).

Comment: I see. Actually you are debugging `strcpy` which is part of libc.so. libc.so is a shared library which is linked to every app by default. So you need to install debugging symbols for libc.so: `sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg`.

Comment: So I did what you said and checked it. It showed the libc6 is detached, is this why I still got the problem with strcpy().`root@19:~# apt-cache search libc6 | grep dbg libc6-dbg - GNU C Library: detached debugging symbols libc6-i386-dbgsym - Debug symbols for libc6-i386 libc6-x32-dbgsym - Debug symbols for libc6-x32 `

Comment: I use 64-bit OS btw.