# __strcpy_sse2_unaligned with -fno-builtin

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, strcpy

I was debugging my program, then the last line happened, how can I fix it? I used the `-fno-builtin` to have a look at the `strcpy()` but it shows that the `__strcpy_sse2_unaligned` is getting called.

```
root@19:~/booksrc# gcc -fno-builtin -g char_array2.c
root@19:~/booksrc# gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) list
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   #include <string.h>
3   
4   int main() {
5      char str_a[20];
6   
7      strcpy(str_a, "Hello World!\n");
8      printf(str_a);
9   }
(gdb) break 6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x708: file char_array2.c, line 6.
(gdb) break strcpy
Breakpoint 2 at 0x5a0
(gdb) break 8
Breakpoint 3 at 0x71b: file char_array2.c, line 8.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/booksrc/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at char_array2.c:7
7      strcpy(str_a, "Hello World!\n");
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, __strcpy_sse2_unaligned ()
    at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:47
47  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__strcpy_sse2_unaligned` is the implementation of `strcpy` which is used on your machine.  glibc automatically chooses an optimized implementation based on CPU characteristics, using an [IFUNC resolver](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-ifunc-function-attribute).

This does not have to do anything with GCC and GCC built-ins.  GCC emits a call to `strcpy`.  It is just that glibc happens to call the function which it `__strcpy_sse2_unaligned`.